# Custom Cordova plugin iOS index.js dosent recognise my .js file

Tags: javascript, ios, cordova, plugins, media

I have written a custom Cordova plugin that brings have as a dependency "Media" plugin.

When i run "cordova plugin add "myPlugin"" the plugin is installed to the sample project however when in my index.js i try to init my plugin it does not recognise it and if i try to create "Media" object it does.

Here is my plugin .xml file :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<plugin xmlns="http://www.phonegap.com/ns/plugins/1.0"
        id="cordova-plugin-MyPlugin"
        version="1.0.0">

  <name> MyPlugin </name>
  <description>Cordova MyPlugin Plugin</description>
  <author> MyPlugin </author>
    <license>MIT</license>
    <keywords> MyPlugin </keywords>

    <dependency id="org.apache.cordova.media"/>


  <js-module src="www/MyPlugin.js" name="MyPlugin">
    <clobbers target="window.plugins.MyPlugin" />
  </js-module>



  <platform name="ios">
    <config-file target="config.xml" parent="/*">
      <feature name="MyPlugin">
        <param name="ios-package" value="CDVMyPlugin" />
      </feature>
    </config-file>

    <!-- Sources -->
    <header-file src="src/ios/CDVMyPlugin.h"/>
    <source-file src="src/ios/CDVMyPlugin.m"/>


    <!-- iOS Frameworks -->
    <framework src="libz.dylib" />

  </platform>

</plugin>
```

Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem apparently was in my "MyPlugin.js" file at the bottom of the file the line :

```
module.exports = MyPlugin;
```

Needs to be added then in the Index.js file (or the file of your choosing) add the following :

//Get a reference to the custom .JS file.

```
myCustomPlugin = cordova.require("cordova-plugin-MyPlugin.MyPlugin");


myPluginInstance = new myCustomPlugin(someParams,onSuccess,onError,null);
```

Now you can access the methods of your .JS file.

Credit to https://stackexchange.com/users/366553/marat-strelets for helping with the solution.